# How do I convert all variables with values of -99 to NA in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I'm working with a high dimensional data set that contains about 200 variables. Many of these variables have values of -99 to indicate they are missing values. I want to convert all these missing values to be expressed as NA instead of -99.

I know that you can do something like

```
df$var1[df$var1 == -99] <- NA
```

but when you have a very large amount of variables this gets extremely tiring and is super tedious and time consuming. I'm importing my data as a data frame and working with that. Is there some clever for loop construction I could do or some nice package/command I could utilize? I'm still a bit new to programming in RStudio. Thanks!

Comment: You might specify that when you import the data. At least from `data.table::fread` I know that you can supply a vector of values to be interpreted as `NA`. The argument is called `na.strings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to solve your issue with `df`:

```
df[df==-99]<-NA
```